# "Cannot open audit interface" upgrading libuuid1 --- is selinux confused?

Tags: debian, chroot, selinux

I have a Debian chroot on a Linux system running an alternative Linux distro. It's always worked fine in the past but in the past few months I've found myself unable to upgrade libuuid1. Instead it complains with:

```
Cannot open audit interface - aborting.
```

This causes dpkg to error out, which means I'm basically unable to install packages any more.

I think this is an interaction with selinux, where my Debian userland thinks it's available but is unable to interact with it. Specifically, I think sudo is trying to open an fd to the audit interface and is getting an unexpected errno (see https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/scm-commits/2010-April/419799.html).

I've hunted around as to whether it's possible to disable it completely at the userland level, but I've only ever found information about disabling it in the kernel, which of course I don't have access to.

I don't know anything about selinux. Are there any ways of lying to my chroot to make it think that selinux isn't there at all? Is there a big userland switch to say 'do not try to interact with it'? The audit interface looks like it works via netlink; are there any ways to override this to make it return the right error code?

Answer (score 0):

You might be running a chroot via qemu-user syscall translation. Check this bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1323001. The commitdiff told us X-Git-Tag: v2.1.0-rc0~52^2~1. So try again with qemu >= v2.1.0